# Why can't the electrons in Lamb-Retherford Experiment transition from 2S to 2P(j=1/2)

Tags: particle-physics, spectroscopy

This experiment reveals metastable state and uses the fact that an electron in 2<sup>2</sup>S<sub>1/2</sub> can't go to the ground state as ∆l=0 is restricted. But I was thinking why doesn't electron go to 2<sup>2</sup>P<sub>1/2</sub> and then transition to 1<sup>2</sup>S<sub>1/2</sub>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electrons do go from $2^{2}S_{1/2}$ to $2^{2}P_{1/2}$ by emitting a microwave of wavelength 28.37cm. This is because $2^{2}S_{1/2}$ is slightly higher in energy compared to $2^{2}P_{1/2}$ due to self interaction of electron by exchange of a photon

[image]

These $2^{2}P_{1/2}$ electrons will subsequently transition to $1^{2}S_{1/2}$. However, in order to experimentally observe this it the $2^{2}P_{1/2}$ state is first transitioned to $2^{2}P_{3/2}$ using a Microwave of frequency 2395 MHz and then the subsequent transition to $1^{2}S_{1/2}$ is experimentally observed as was done in the Lamb Retherford experiment.

Comment: If they do go from 2<sup>2</sup>S<sub>1/2</sub> to 2<sup>2</sup>P<sub>1/2</sub> then how does 2<sup>2</sup>S<sub>1/2</sub> become a metastable state? And it is a stable state because galvanometer gives a reading. Is there some probability thing going on?

Comment: That comes from Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. As $\Delta T = \frac{\hbar}{\Delta E}$, the transition from $2^{2}S_{1/2}$ to $2^{2}P_{1/2}$ has a very small energy difference so it spends a lot time in $2^{2}S_{1/2}$ before it transitions to $2^{2}P_{1/2}$. Hence, it is metastable.